# Bigquery - Windowed Aggregation YoY

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to use a window function,for each day of sales of a sku, to have the sum of the last 365 days of qty of the sku.  If this was sold on every day then I could use  ROWS and PRECEDING etc

```
ORDER BY
      CalendarFullDate ROWS BETWEEN 364 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

But in this case, the dates are not evenly distributed with many days not having a sale (i.e I cant just go back 364 rows and assume a sale is every day).

So with the test/sample below, is it possible to use windowing and some type of where clause so Im only summing back at most 364 days?

```
WITH samples AS (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-10-27") AS CalendarFullDate, 86.0 AS DailySalesQty UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-10-20"), 84.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-09-29"), 88.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-09-14"), 42.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-09-01"), 21.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-05-05"), 25.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-04-28"), 97.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-03-31"), 244.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-03-24"), 68.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-02-23"), 52.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-02-10"), 48.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-01-21"), 243.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-01-18"), 2.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2018-01-06"), 190.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-12-26"), 310.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-12-09"), 240.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-11-03"), 30.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-10-21"), 164.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-09-30"), 44.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-09-09"), 55.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-09-01"), 35.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-05-20"), 60.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-05-06"), 68.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "1" AS SKU, DATE("2017-04-15"), 136.0) UNION ALL (

  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-10-24"), 46.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-10-18"), 56.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-09-16"), 19.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-09-02"), 42.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-09-01"), 45.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-07-05"), 25.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-06-28"), 210.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-05-31"), 44.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-05-24"), 168.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-04-23"), 152.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-03-10"), 8.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-02-21"), 23.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-01-18"), 20.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2018-01-06"), 10.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-12-26"), 30.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-11-09"), 1240.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-11-03"), 323.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-10-21"), 123.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-09-30"), 444.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-09-09"), 555.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-08-01"), 35.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-06-20"), 6.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-05-06"), 68.0 ) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-04-15"), 136.0) UNION ALL (
  SELECT "2" AS SKU, DATE("2017-04-09"), 136.0)
)

SELECT 
  SKU, 
  CalendarFullDate, 
  SUM(DailySalesQty) OVER(win)
FROM
  samples WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY
      SKU
    ORDER BY
      CalendarFullDate 
    RANGE BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(CalendarFullDate,INTERVAL 364 DAY) AND CalendarFullDate)
```

I know above you cant do for RANGE, but its a sort of pseudo code for what I actually want to do.  I tried a where clause but thats not allowed.

Is this even possible using windowing?  Its a nice clean way to do it but not sure if I can express such a condition for the windowed aggregate?

Note: this is a cut down version of the real data which has 5 fields as the partition, and 20 odd measures to aggregate as well and is a huge dataset (1 TB) so wanting it to be efficient as well.

Thoughts?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
    SKU, 
    CalendarFullDate,
    SUM(DailySalesQty) OVER(win) SalesQty365days
FROM (
  SELECT 
    SKU, 
    CalendarFullDate, 
    DailySalesQty,
    UNIX_DATE(CalendarFullDate) unix_days
  FROM samples 
)
WINDOW win AS (
  PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY unix_days 
  RANGE BETWEEN 364 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
)
```

the trick here is in 'translating' `CalendarFullDate` field of DATE type into INTEGER number of days since epoch so it can be used in ORDER BY and RANGE parts of WINDOW expression

Comment: worked a charm :) . Thanks once again!  Love your work. K

Comment: sure. any update on 'global alias' question - did it work for you?